# Insert data when selecting a dropdown option, MySQL, JAVA, JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

well my english is not so good, but i will try to explain me, I have a question about how to make an INSERT query when selecting an option from my dropdown, I explain myself, I have a section to insert a user on my website, and an option to select a profile

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRNtp.png)

It should be noted that my dropdown options are data from my PROFILE table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG8lP.png)

This is my code where I show the values ​​of my dropdown from my PROFILE table

```html
<select class="form-control" style="width: 250px"> 
                            <option value="-1">Selecciona un perfil</option>
                            <% 
                                try
                                {
                                    String Query = "SELECT * FROM perfil";
                                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registrousuario","root", "");
                                    
                                    Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
                                    ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(Query);
                                    while(rs.next())
                                    {  
                                        %>
                                           <option value="<%=rs.getString("idPerfil")%>"><%=rs.getString("nombrePerfil")%></option>
                                        <%
                                    }
                                }
                                catch(Exception ex)
                                {
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                    out.println("Error: "+ex.getMessage());
                                }
                            %>  
                        </select>
```

what I try to do in my table USER

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvJk3.png)

is to insert the option either EMPLOYEE or PROFILE dropdown

my INSERT query is as follows

```html
@RequestMapping(value = "agregar.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView Agregar(Persona p)
    {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO usuario(claveUsuario, nombre, apellido, email, contrasena, idPerfil) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        this.jdbcTemplate.update(sql,p.getClave(), p.getNom(), p.getApe(), p.getCorreo(), p.getPass(), p.getIdPerfil());
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/index.htm");
    }
```

I insert the other data correctly, only I need to be able to insert the values ​​of my DROPDOWN in my USER table

I don't know if I would miss doing a JOIN to my PROFILE table in my INSERT query, in order to register the profile data to my USER table

I hope I have explained well, any help would be very important

Comment: How are you passing the dropdown value to the controller? How are you building the `Persona` object that is the argument for the `Agregar(p)` method when invoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the `id` and `name` of the `select` element. It should be as follows:

```
<select id="idPerfil" name="idPerfil" class="form-control" style="width: 250px">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this code, if you chose the first one the insert have in role Admin and for the second you have in you database a normal user:

```
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="role">
    <option selected>select Role</option>
    <option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
    <option value="User">User</option>
</select>
```